# Stored Procedure returns Empty result set on Optional paramaters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

When I pass all the values required in query in return correct results. But when I only pass the ID, I get an empty result set. Shouldn't it be ignore the type in that case and still return the correct values?

Can you help me out with this and point out the issues in the query.

```
SELECT 'elementary_school' AS type, elementary_school AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM data
WHERE data.report_id = ReportId         
AND (data.book_section = type 
     OR data.book_section IS NULL
     OR data.book_section = ''
    )
GROUP BY elementary_school


UNION

SELECT 'middle_school' AS type, middle_school AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM data
WHERE data.report_id = ReportId     
AND (data.book_section = type 
     OR data.book_section IS NULL
     OR data.book_section = ''
    )
 GROUP BY  middle_school


UNION

SELECT 'high_school' AS type, high_school AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM data
WHERE data.report_id = ReportId     
AND (data.book_section = type 
     OR data.book_section IS NULL
     OR data.book_section = ''
    )
GROUP BY high_school     



UNION

SELECT 'lot_sqft' AS type, lot_sqft AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM data
WHERE data.report_id = ReportId     
AND (data.book_section = type 
     OR data.book_section IS NULL
     OR data.book_section = ''
    )
GROUP BY lot_sqft       

ORDER BY count, type
```

Comment: What are you talking about?  What id?

Comment: ReportId variable which would be an integer. and ID of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query:

```
SELECT t.type,
        (CASE WHEN t.type = 'elementary_school' THEN elementary_school 
              WHEN t.type = 'middle_school' THEN middle_school 
              WHEN t.type = 'high_school' THEN high_school 
              WHEN t.type = 'lot_sqft' THEN lot_sqft 

         END) AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM data d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 'elementary_school' AS type UNION ALL
      SELECT 'middle_school' AS type UNION ALL
      SELECT 'high_school' AS type UNION ALL
      SELECT 'lot_sqft' AS type
     ) t
WHERE d.report_id = @ReportId AND
      (d.book_section = @type OR 
       d.book_section IS NULL OR
       d.book_section = ''
      )
GROUP BY t.type. obj;
```

I have highlighted what seem to be "parameters" using `@` to clarify that they are parameters and not columns in tables.

If you want to check for a `NULL` value, then change the logic to:

```
WHERE (d.report_id = @ReportId OR @ReportId IS NULL) AND
      (d.book_section = @type OR 
       d.book_section IS NULL OR
       d.book_section = ''
      )
```

Comment: This part will return 'elementary_school' every time for type. No?

`SELECT 'elementary_school' AS type,
        (CASE WHEN t.type = 'elementary_school' THEN elementary_school 
              WHEN t.type = 'middle_school' THEN middle_school 
              WHEN t.type = 'high_school' THEN high_school 
              WHEN t.type = 'lot_sqft' THEN lot_sqft 

         END) AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman . . . The type should be coming from the `t` table.

Comment: Alright, But still it only makes the query short. Still we get the same results.

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was a logical error. But that's for letting for know a new way to write this query. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, It was a silly but honest mistake. I was able to figure it out myself. The problem was I was checking if the column was null or empty but not checking on the value I passed. So it would be something like as follows:

```
AND (data.book_section = type 
 OR data.book_section IS NULL
 OR data.book_section = ''
)
```

Converted To:

```
AND (data.book_section = type 
 OR type IS NULL
 OR type = ''
)
```

As I only want to check if it was the 'type' which I'm passing a param is empty or null. Anyways way thanks for everyone who tried to help. Cheers.